# How to session logout automatically after 10 minutes of inactivity in expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, logout

I am using this code for session in app.js

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: config.sessionKey,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    maxAge: 600*1000

}));
```

I just read somewhere I need to enable the maxAge as time limit to do so. Is it correct? Have I done it right?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `maxAge` property in cookie-

```
app.use(session({
    secret: config.sessionKey,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 600 * 1000
    }
}));
```